# CodeRush code cleanup formatting

Tags: coderush

I have a few classes that are a complete mess.
I would like for CodeRush to organize the code so that public, private, etc. methods become grouped. I would also like for CodeRush to organize my public methods into a region, and put fields and properties into regions.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the CR_ClassCleaner plugin -

http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CR_ClassCleaner

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the CR_ClassCleaner plug-in, there's a lighter and simplified version of such functionality in the [CR_MemberOrganizer](http://www.skorkin.com/2011/04/organizing-source-code-and-sorting-class-members-using-coderush/) plug-in shipped in CodeRush as an open source feature.